# Postgres create many to many relationship to table with composite primary key

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."Users" (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    "createdAt" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);

CREATE TABLE "public"."Boards" (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "ownerId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "createdAt" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY ("ownerId") REFERENCES "public"."Users"(id)
);

CREATE TABLE "public"."Board_Members"(
    "userId" SERIAL,
    "boardId" SERIAL,
    CONSTRAINT board_member_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("userId", "boardId"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES "public"."Users"(id),
    FOREIGN KEY ("boardId") REFERENCES "public"."Boards"(id)
);

CREATE TABLE "public"."Columns" (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "boardId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "createdAt" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY ("boardId") REFERENCES "public"."Boards"(id)
);

CREATE TABLE "public"."Cards" (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    dueDate TIMESTAMP,
    "columnId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "createdAt" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY ("columnId") REFERENCES "public"."Columns"(id),
);
```

I have these tables. Now I want to have a field called "assignee" in "Cards" table which will be a many-to-many relationship with "userId" from "Board_Members" table just like "Boards" and "Users" have a many-to-maany relationship. How do I do that? Do I create a new table and just reference the "userId" column as FK?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a table with 2 foreign keys.

And because I think you want to switch the cards, from person to person. you could also want to keep track of the played history. See also the first normal form to check if your database is designed right.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

I hope I answered your question :)

Comment: So I should just add a table with cardId(Cards table) and userID(Board_Members table)? Will this make it so that only a board member can be assigned to a card and prevent other users who are not part of this board?

Comment: Well to prevent this you need to make a bussiness rule.

Comment: What business rule? I was thinking since Board_Members table already has composite PK this will automatically prevent users who are not part of this board from being assigned to a card?

Comment: if players is in board and doens't have the card than insert else throw error. you can also add  the board foreignkey in the same table to let 1 player at a time have a card. but not sure if that is needed.

Comment: This would be a kanban board app. So a user can belong to many boards and a board can have many users. Board also has many columns. A column has many cards. I want to assign users to a card who are only members of the board to which the card belongs.

Comment: I tried making a another table with two foreign keys but it doesn't work because I can't refer to the composite PK. How do I do that?

Comment: https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipO_da_gfhlbkQGxd6sCiC9eUXfpORmRwMklnYNau9EVNTnA4kinU3EZvhrVEQMN7Q?key=ejZWT3Z4WExtSlZIOXc3c2JQWWdsYnVhVnQ3TzdR Just made your erd. and just give it a AI value as PK

Comment: You are just missing one more table "Columns" between Boards and Cards tables. Thank you for the ERD. So I don't have to refer to the "Boards_Members" table at all to create this relationship only referring to the Users table would suffice. This is where I was getting confused.

Comment: Should use a other word for Columns maybe that one is reserved use something like bucket or something else. but columns is a many to 1 relationship with cards. where cards is on the 1 side